# Why is ReactJS not performant like raw JS for simple, stupid proof of concept?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Years ago, I heard about a nice 404 page and [implemented a copy](https://CJSHayward.com/missing.html).

In working with ReactJS, [the same idea](http://demo.Pragmatometer.com) is intended to be implemented, but it is slow and jerky in its motion, and after a while Chrome gives it an "unresponsive script" warning, pinpointed to line 1226, "var position = index % repeated_tokens.length;", with a few hundred milliseconds' delay between successive calls. The script consistently goes beyond an unresponsive page to bringing a computer to its knees.

Obviously, they're not the same implementation, although the ReactJS version is derived from the "I am not using jQuery yet" version. But beyond that, why is it bogging? Am I making a deep stack of closures? Why is [the ReactJS port](http://demo.pragmatometer.com) slower than [the bare JavaScript original](https://cjshayward.com/missing.html)?

In both cases the work is driven by minor arithmetic and there is nothing particularly interesting about the code or what it is doing.

--UPDATE--

I see I've gotten a downvote and three close votes...

This appears to have gotten response from people who are (a) saying something sensible and (b) contradicting what Pete Hunt and other people have said.

What is claimed, among other things, by Hunt and Facebook's ReactJS video, is that the synthetic DOM is lightning-fast, enough to pull 60 frames per second on a non-JIT iPhone. And they've left an optimization hook to say "Ignore this portion of the DOM in your fast comparison," which I've used elsewhere to disclaim jurisdiction of a non-ReactJS widget.

@EdBallot's suggestion that it's "an extreme (and unnecessary) amount of work to create and render an element, and do a single document.getElementById. Now I'm factoring out that last bit; DOM manipulation is slow. But the responses here are hard to reconcile with what Facebook has been saying about performant ReactJS. There is a "Crunch all you want; we'll make more" attitude about (theoretically) throwing away the DOM and making a new one, which is lightning-fast because it's done in memory without talking to the real DOM.

In many cases I want something more surgical and can attempt to change the smallest area possible, but the letter and spirit of ReactJS videos I've seen is squarely in the spirit of "Crunch all you want; we'll make more."

Off to trying suggested edits to see what they will do...

Comment: The code really needs to be posted here for this to be something anybody can answer. The behavior you describe is very suggestive of an implementation defect.

Comment: Out of the box ReactJs performs extremely well, There is likely a problem with the code, but it's impossible to help without a reproducible example of the issue.

Comment: Just a quick glance in Chrome dev tools shows your div with id `marvin` is being re-built constantly. That would definitely account for the performance problem. I also saw a lot of setInterval code in the footer JS. You want to limit the amount of DOM manipulation you're doing to only when it's necessary.

Comment: @Pointy, the code is at http://pastebin.com/Y5TBJfd1

Comment: @MarcBaumbach, I think you're looking at the "It's working" version. The original page at cjsh.name/missing.html works quickly as far as I can tell; 100ms is a lot of time for doing a single DOM manipulation, and I haven't observed the original "It's working" version to ever bog. The "not working yet" version at demo.pragmatometer.com with code at http://pastebin.com/Y5TBJfd1 is doing more, and maybe something else may be a problem. But while DOM manipulations are slow next to ReactJS and its competitors, making one change every 100 seconds is practically Maytag repairman mode in website time.

Comment: ReactJs, like any 3rd party library, has its quirks that you need to learn to make it truly efficient. I'm not going to go into detail about all of them, but I'd recommend making sure you understand the lifecycle functions, `shouldComponentUpdate`, and read about the component `key` property. While React has a shadow dom, it is only moderately efficient unless you understand how to make your components use it effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look at all the code, but for starters, this is rather inefficient

```
var update = function() {
  React.render(React.createElement(Pragmatometer, null),
    document.getElementById('main'));
  for(var instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
  }
  save('Scratchpad', document.getElementById('scratchpad').value);
};
var update_interval = setInterval(update, 100);
```

It is doing an extreme (and unnecessary) amount of work and it is being done every 100ms. Among other things, it is calling:

- `React.createElement`
- `React.render`
- `document.getElementById`

Probably with the amount of JS objects being created and released, your `update` function plus garbage collection is taking longer than 100ms, effectively taking the computer to its knees and lower.

At the very least, I'd recommend caching as much as you can outside of the interval callback. Also no need to call `React.render` multiple times. Once it is rendered into the dom, use `setProps` or `forceUpdate` to cause it to render changes.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
var mainComponent = React.createElement(Pragmatometer, null);
React.render(mainComponent,
  document.getElementById('main'));

var update = function() {
  mainComponent.forceUpdate();
  for(var instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
  }
  save('Scratchpad', document.getElementById('scratchpad').value);
};
var update_interval = setInterval(update, 100);
```

Beyond that, I'd also recommend moving the setInterval code into whatever React component is rendering that stuff (the `Scratchpad` component?).

A final comment: one of the downsides of using `setInterval` is that it doesn't wait for the callback function to complete before queuing up the next callback. An alternative is to use `setTimeout` with the callback setting up the next `setTimeout`, like this

```
var update = function() {
  // do some stuff

  // update is done to setup the next timeout
  setTimeout(update, 100);
};
setTimeout(update, 100);
```